# Expanding and collapsing nested DIVs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have html which has nested DIVs. And they are in turn  expandable links.
I want to introduce Expand all and collapse all buttons so that
1. Expand all - will  expand the inner (nested) DIVs also.
2. Collapse all - collapses all DIVs and keeps only the first (parent) DIV

Can someone help me in this regard.
I am using HTML and Javascript.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="my in myGroups.group" class="myjobs">
            <accordion close-others="false">
                <accordion-group is-open="isopen">
                    <accordion-heading >
                        <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i> Job Group XYZASD
                    </accordion-heading>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed ">
                                <tr><td>Name</td><td>{{my.name}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Age</td><td>{{my.age}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Location</td><td>{{my.location}}</td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div ng-repeat="myjobb in my.jobs.job">
                                <accordion close-others="false">
                                    <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-class="{'panel panel-danger': job.expired }">
                                        <accordion-heading>
                                            <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>  Personal Details : {{job.id}} Description: {{job.desc}}
                                            <span ng-show="job.expired" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="The job is expired"></span>
                                        </accordion-heading>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                                            <tr><td>Designation</td><td>{{job.dsg}}</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Company</td><td>{{job.comp}}</td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                    </accordion-group>
                                </accordion>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

my js:

```
$('#expand-all').click(function() {
        $('.slide').slideDown();
        });
    $('#contract-all').click(function() {
        $('.slide').slideUp();
        });
```

Problem with this is the main  DIV also goes from the html page in browser

Comment: Seems to be [tag:angular] view why do you need jQuery?

Comment: Expand-all and collapse all:
<p ng-show="myGroups.group">
            <span id="expand-all"><b>Expand all</b></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span id="contract-all"><b>Collapse all</b></span>
        </p>

Comment: do not use jquery in angulars since it can be done without it